# Как осуществить проверку на наличие файла в flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Вопрос заключается в следующем:

Есть страница, написанная на Flask, на ней пользователь вводит в поле URL адрес и нажимает на кнопку. После этого URL сохраняется и отправляется в функцию get_data(), которая спустя некоторое время сохраняет массив JSON с собранными данными. На сайте пользователь нажимает на кнопку "Скачать" и ему прилетает тот самый JSON файл. Нужно сделать так, что бы пока файл не появился, по нажатии на кнопку "Скачать" рядом высвечивалось что-то типа "Подождите, идет сбор данных", а когда файл появится, надпись пропадала и/или замещалась другой надписью, типа "Файл готов к скачиванию". Файлы app.py и index.html прикладываю

app.py

```
def check():
    if os.path.exists('files/data.json'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/add_url', methods=['POST'])
def add_file():
    text = request.form['text']
    scrap.get_data(text)
    return redirect(url_for('main'))

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    return send_file('files/data.json', as_attachment=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/add_url">
        <h2>Give me URL</h2>
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="{{ url_for('download') }}">Скачать</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Подобное делается через JavaScript и никак иначе

Comment: я понимаю, js можно подключить к flask. вопрос остается открытым